# Match every second character

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match every second character in a string with a regular expression:

```
'abcdef'.match(???) => ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

I have this non-regex solution:

```
spl = []; for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) spl.push(str.charAt(i));
```

but looking for something more elegant.

Comment: You sure you need a regex for this?

Comment: Agreed with @Fabrício Matté why not to iterate over string by it's length and get charAt(i)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
'abcdefg'.replace(/.(.)?/g, '$1').split('');
```

It doesn't require any shims.

Comment: Interesting line of thought. But I believe the regex should be `/(.)./g` - the OP's output matches at the first character and there's no need to replace when the capturing group doesn't match.

Comment: Clever solution! Your regex matches the question title ("match every second character") and so outputs ["b", "d"] for the OP's sample text `"abcde"`, but the question text made clear the OP wants ["a", "c", "e"] instead (the first character and every other one after it).

Comment: Yes, my title is somehow confusing but you got it right, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without regex as well.

```
'abcdef'.split("").filter(function(v, i){ return i % 2 === 0; });
```

If IE<=8 support is an issue, you may add [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

---

Another solution, more verbose but with better performance which doesn't require shims:

```
var str = "abcdef", output = [];
for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    output.push(str.charAt(i));
}
```

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/split-and-filter-vs-for-loop/4)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Awesome idea. `=]` I tend to overcomplicate things lol.

Comment: You can leave out the map+filter if you add another way of doing this... it's needlessly complex, slow, idiotic and bulky... embarrassing really... If you want to see overcomplicating, let me know :D

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ohhh my bad, you meant the map+filter that you posted on your answer, my bad. Removing it from the jsperf.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `..?` and the [ES5 `map` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) (which can be supplied by a shim for browsers that don't yet have it natively):

```
"abcde".match(/..?/g).map(function(value) { return value.charAt(0); });
// ["a", "c", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.prototype.map` is an option, too:

```
var oddChars = Array.prototype.map.call('abcdef', function(i,k)
{
    if (k%2===0)
    {
        return i;
    }
}).filter(function(x)
{
    return x;
    //or if falsy values are an option:
    return !(x === undefined);
});
```

`oddChars` is now `["a","c","e"]`...

Comment: Apparently, it could be just `filter`, no need for `map`.